# Candidate Elimination Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Consider the following training data sets..

```
+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
| Size  | Color | Shape    | Class/Label |
+=======+=======+==========+=============+
| big   | red   | circle   | No          |
| small | red   | triangle | No          |
| small | red   | circle   | Yes         |
| big   | blue  | circle   | No          |
| small | blue  | circle   | Yes         |
+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

I would like to understand how the algorithm proceeds when it starts with a negative example and when two negative examples come together.

This is not an assignment question by the way.

Examples with other data sets are also welcome! This is to understand the negative part of the algorithm.

Comment: the training set contains 3 attributes and the last one is the classification data whether +ve or -ve. Can you explain how the G,S sets expand as each training data is considered?? @YvesDaoust

Comment: @SeanOwen There actually is something special about "Yes" and "No". A "Yes" label results in a generalization of the Specific hypotheses, wheres "No" results in a specialization of the General hypotheses.

Comment: @user3419395 - There was an error in my initial answer, which I just corrected.

Comment: @bogatron. Oh, I just looked up 'Candidate Elimination Algorithm'. I had no idea it was a specific thing. Oops, you are right then.

Comment: @bogatron can you explain how the minimal specialization is <?, ?, triangle> and not <?,?,circle> ?

Comment: @sheldoncooper The reason is that the first example, `(big, red, circle)`, is a negative one so you have to replace `<?, ?, ?>` with minimal specializations that are *inconsistent* with that example. `<?,?,circle>` (all circles) is still consistent with `(big, red, circle)`, whereas `<?, ?, triangle>` (all triangles) is not.

Comment: @bogatron Thanks for making it easy to understand

Comment: G1 = {<small, ? , ?>, <?, blue, ?>, <?, ?, triangle>} why not G1 = {<big, ? , ?>, <?, red, ?>, <?, ?, triangle>}

Comment: @sheldoncooper Because neither `<big, ? , ?>` (all big shapes) nor `<?, red, ?>` (all red shapes) are inconsistent with `(big, red, circle)`. When you are presented with a negative example, all the specializations of `G` must be *inconsistent* with the example.

Comment: @bogatron why `G1` contains `Color=blue` when this attribute value first appears in the 4th training example? I mean this attribute cannot be known at this time, no? The algorithm defined on page 33 of the book only knows one training example per time.

Comment: @Tim, the "G" hypotheses are the most general hypotheses. `<?, blue, ?>` is in G1 because blue objects (of any shape or size) are still in the hypothesis space (they weren't ruled out by the negative example).

Comment: Thanks, I now saw that iff the very first example is negative the algorithm has to determine all possible values and thus your example is correct! Unfortunately that is not described in the book. The book only has an example where is starts with a positive value and there the G borders are trivial to calculate. When I change the order by switching example 1 and 3 the easy algorithm can be used again and calculates the same result as yours without having to know further attribute values.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

For your hypothesis space (H), you start with your sets of maximally general (G) and maximally specific (S) hypotheses:

```
G0 = {<?, ?, ?>}
S0 = {<0, 0, 0>}
```

When you are presented with a negative example, you need to remove from S any hypothesis inconsistent with the current observation and replace any inconsistent hypothesis in G with its minimal specializations that are consistent with the observation but still more general than some member of S.

So for your first (negative) example, `(big, red, circle)`, the minimal specializations would make the new hypothesis space

```
G1 = {<small, ? , ?>, <?, blue, ?>, <?, ?, triangle>}
S1 = S0 = {<0, 0, 0>}
```

Note that S did not change. For your next example, `(small, red, triangle)`, which is also negative, you will need to further specialize G. Note that the second hypothesis in G1 does not match the new observation so only the first and third hypotheses in G1 need to be specialized. That would yield

```
G2 = {<small, blue, ?>, <small, ?, circle>, <?, blue, ?>, <big, ?, triangle>, <?, blue, triangle>}
```

However, since the first and last hypotheses in G2 above are specializations of the middle hypothesis (`<?, blue, ?>`), we drop those two, giving

```
G2 = {<small, ?, circle>, <?, blue, ?>, <big, ?, triangle>}
S2 = S1 = S0 = {<0, 0, 0>}
```

For the positive `(small, red, circle)` observation, you must generalize S and remove anything in G that is inconsistent, which gives

```
G3 = {<small, ?, circle>}
S3 = {<small, red, circle>}
```

`(big, blue, circle)` is the next negative example. But since it in not consistent with G, there is nothing to do so

```
G4 = G3 = {<small, ?, circle>}
S4 = S3 = {<small, red, circle>}
```

Lastly, you have the positive example of `(small, blue, circle)`, which requires you to generalize S to make it consistent with the example, giving

```
G5 = {<small, ?, circle>}
S5 = {<small, ?, circle>}
```

Since G and S are equal, you have learned the concept of "small circles".

Comment: Where can i get a good tutorial on working out this algorithm step by step.

Comment: Not quite step-by-step, but helpful https://artint.info/html/ArtInt_191.html#bool-conc-ex @Joseph